# Joining multiple values from one table to a shared value on another table

Tags: sql, join, toad

I apologize if this problem has been posted, but I don't really know how to describe it properly except to use an example.

To simplify my problem, I've created the following tables.

Essentially, I would like to link

1. FRUIT.COLOUR_ID to COLOURSHAPES.VALUE
2. FRUIT.SHAPE_ID to CLOURSHAPES.VALUE

However, what I want to display is COLOURSHAPES.VALUE as 2 separate columns.
In addition, I would like to have each fruit displayed as many times as their availabilities exist.

```
FRUITNAME   COLOUR  SHAPE   AVAILABILITY
ORANGE  ORANGE  ROUND   METRO
ORANGE  ORANGE  ROUND   LOBLAWS


TABLE #1: FRUIT         
FRUIT_ID    FRUITNAME   COLOUR_ID   SHAPE_ID
1   ORANGE  10  20
2   BANANA  11  21
3   APPLE   12  20
4   PEAR    13  20

TABLE #2: COLOURSHAPES          
VALUE   DESCRIPTION     
10  ORANGE      
11  YELLOW      
12  RED     
13  BROWN       
20  ROUND       
21  LONG        

TABLE #3: AVAILABILITY          
FRUIT_ID    STORE       
1   METRO       
1   LOBLAWS     
2   FRESHCO     
3   METRO       
4   FRESHCO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join to Table2 twice, once to get colour and again to get shape.

```
select T3.FRUIT_ID, T1.FRUIT_NAME, T3.STORE, T2A.DESCRIPTION, T2B.DESCRIPTION
from TABLE3 T3
join TABLE1 T1
left join TABLE2 T2A on T1.COLOUR_ID=T2A.VALUE
left join TABLE2 T2B on T1.SHAPE_ID=T2B.VALUE
```

Comment: missing an `on` between table3 and table1, you'd also need a join between your t2a and t2b to eliminate dupes

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize you can join the same table twice by calling it something different.